# How can I edit text in right-to-left direction in Eclipse (on Windows)?

Tags: eclipse, right-to-left, i18n

The [official website of Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fbidi.html) says that they support RTL text editing. They say that, in order to activate RTL support, Eclipse should be started from the command line with argument: `-bidi "on=y;textDir=ltr"`. I did this, but Eclipse still shows my Hebrew file left-to-right. I tried to change the file's properties, but, it only lets me change the encoding - not the direction.

How can I tell Eclipse to let me edit the file in a RTL direction?

Comment: Have you set in your project manifest RTL support?

Comment: My project contains only plain text files... where is the project manifest and how do I change it?

Comment: I see. What I suggest is applicable for application projects

Comment: Is there something Windows-specific about your question? Or is it just because you're currently using Windows?